# Create file name with current date

Tags: c#, datetime, directory

In my C# Windows Forms application I have log data. I save them in a text file,
but I want to name this file with some description with the current date/Time. But while debugging the code I got this error:

> The given path's format is not supported.

here's my code:

```
        string dateAndTime = " '' " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " '' ";
        string sPath = @"C:/Desktop/Logs - "+ dateAndTime + ".txt";
        int type = 0;
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(sPath))
        {
            int J = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < logsList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (logsList[i + 3] == "IN")
                {
                    type = 3;
                }
                else if (logsList[i + 3] == "OUT")
                {
                    type = 4;
                }

                sw.WriteLine(logsList[i] + "          " + logsList[i + 1] + "       " + logsList[i + 2] + "     " + logsList[i + 3] + "     " + logsList[i + 4]);
                i += 4;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the path exactly?

Comment: string sPath = @"C:\Users\Ziad.Mansour\Desktop\Logs - " + DeviceID.ToString() + dateAndTime + ".txt";

Answer (score 8):

Use this for  a format with  no slashes

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss");
```

ToShortDateString uses the current language which will result in different results depending on the machine where the code executes

Answer (score 1):

Your file name format is wrong, this kind of file name formats will not be supported by the operating system.

**i.e :** your file name contains `/` and `:`, Which are special characters that are not supported by the operating system to name the file.

That's why you are getting the error saying

> The given path's format is not supported.

[image: File Name is wrong]

> Also i would suggest you to do not use the special chars like this `"
>   '' "`. Its not required there.

Use this below code if you wish this kind of file name formats `C:/Desktop/Logs - 7-1-2015-3-45 PM.txt`.

*Sample Code for Valid File Name:*

```
string dateAndTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
dateAndTime = dateAndTime.Replace('/', '-');
dateAndTime = dateAndTime.Replace(':', '-');
```